# scrollview form with autolayout

Tags: ios, autolayout

I'm trying to build a scrollview form in my app. So, there is the EditForm (which is a uiviewcontroller) which contains a scrollview which contains a contentView (uiview), which contains my fields.

How do I initialize all these views with autolayout ? To say to the scrollview to take the entire size of the contentView (i'm adding subview on contentView), to the scrollView to be on the uiviewcontroller, and of course, for the scrollView to scroll properly depending of the size of contentView.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, this is very easy to do so.

I personally like use pure code without any IB in my applications. First check this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2154/_index.html) from Apple.

Basic step is:

1. Make sure all your subviews are translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
2. Add constraints for your views using [VFL](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/VisualFormatLanguage/VisualFormatLanguage.html)

Tips for UIScrollView for AutoLayout - You need to add bottom constraints for your bottom subviews so that scroll view can be scrollable.

Good Luck : )

Comment: Ok thanks ! but what do you mean for the bottom constraint ? have an example ?

Comment: OK, If we don't use auto layout, we need to set content size for scrolling, right? In auto layout mode, we don't set content size for scrollView. Instead, we give constraints to bottom line of scrollview so that scrollview knows the size of content for scrolling.

Comment: Oh okay, the contentSize can't be automatically determined ?

Comment: Nope. You should provide more details for scrolling. It is not that smart. Any way, check apple example. It already did it by this code:@"V:|[imageView]|". You can see imageView's bottom is just against ScrollView's bottom. This will give content size for scrolling.

Comment: The problem is that I have a dynamic tableview in the contentView. Users can click and add a row to the contentView, so I need the scrollView's contentSize to increase too. So, no solution without doing a lot of calculation ?

Comment: If you can add constraints to views then you can remove constraints from view. So whenever there is changes on dynamic tableview, just remove and add constraints. I had a similar application doing this way :)